# Getting Component State

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have component named Vault

```
   class Vault Component{

    State : { animal: dog,color:blue} 
}
```

Lets say I have button in component named App with a button

```
class App Component{

State: { animal:null,color:null}

}
<div onCLick = {goGetVaultData()} className="button">Press Me</div>
```

Question is how does goGetVaultData function look to extract state from a diffrent component

```
goGetVaultData(){

// what do I look like ?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data from a parent component, have the parent pass it down as a prop, then access it using `this.props`.

If you want data from a child component, pass a function as a prop to the child. The child calls that function, and when they do you call `this.setState` to save the value, and access it later using `this.state`

If you want data from a sibling component, move the state up to whatever component is the common ancestor of the two components. That common ancestor passes props down to both components.

Comment: Okay I'll mess with that

Comment: Was trying to figure out if there is an alternative way is all